# Find a correct form for $|u^h-1|\leq |h| |\log u| u^h$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-transforms

I am reading the article "*A Direct Approach to the Mellin Transform*". 
To prove Lemma 2 (see below), the authors used the following inequality
\begin{equation} (I): \hspace{1cm}
|u^h-1|\leq |h| |\log u| u^h,
\end{equation}
where $h\in\mathbb{C}$ $\left(|h|<\delta\right)$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Then they wrote
\begin{align}(II): \hspace{1cm}
|f_{\mathcal{M}}^{\wedge}\left(s+h\right)-f_{\mathcal{M}}^{\wedge}\left(s\right)|
&\leq
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f\left(u\right)\left(u^{s+h-1}-u^{s-1}\right)|\mathrm{d}u\\
&\leq |h|
\int_{0}^{\infty}|f\left(u\right)\left(\log u\right)u^{s+h-1}|\mathrm{d}u,
\end{align}
where $f_{\mathcal{M}}^{\wedge}\left(s\right)$ is the Mellin transform of $f$. However, I can not prove **the first inequality**, and I think it is wrong. 
I want to use the elementary inequality
\begin{equation}
|e^z-1|\leq |z|e^{|z|}.
\end{equation}
But what I can get is
\begin{equation}
|u^h-1|=|e^{h\log u}-1|\leq |h| |\log u| e^{|h \log u|}.
\end{equation}
**My question**: Can we find a corrected version of inequality (I) s.t. the second inequality (II) can be simply proved by using the corrected version ?
[image]

Comment: Looks as if something is wrong in (I). When $u$ is smaller than one and $h$ positive it is false. Your inequality is correct

Comment: But my inequality can not prove the inequality (II). I think there must be a simple way to get the inequality (II).

Comment: (II) is also wrong in the stated form (f support in (0,1), h pos). But you probably don't need exactly this for the rest (but the paper should perhaps have been refereed more carefully?)

Comment: The paper may contain some errors or typos, but I think the main results are reliable. In fact, it do provide a good way to understand the Mellin transform. I will try another way to prove the result.

Comment: You may also just add to your text above the result you want to prove with the inequality, and I can have a look. Anyway, good luck with the sequel.

Comment: I have added some information.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there seems to be a misprint in (2.5). I suppose it should be $\log u$ times the given power of $u$ (as they use below). Supposing this, if the authors have not made similar mistakes in proving (the correct version of) (2.5) then the last inequality is correct.
 Let $|h|<\delta$.
My the MVT (using a path $th, 0\leq t\leq 1$ from 0 to $h$) we get
$$ |u^h -1| = |e^{h \log u} - 1| 
\leq |h||\log u| \sup_{0\leq t\leq 1} |u^{th}|
\leq |h||\log u| \sup_{|k|<\delta} |u^k|
$$

For $0<u\leq 1$, $|k|<\delta$ 
you have $|u^{k}|\leq u^{-\delta}$ and for $u\geq 1$ you have $|u^k|\leq u^{\delta}$ which fits with the (correct version of) inequality (2.5) to give the stated bound.  The authors (or referees) should have been more vigilant.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, since $|u^h-1|\leq |h| |\log u| e^{|h| |\log u|}$, we have $|u^h-1|\leq |h| |\log u| e^{-|h| \log u}$ for $u\in(0,1]$; $|u^h-1|\leq |h| |\log u| e^{|h| \log u}$ for $u\in[1,\infty)$, the same result that you derived via using MVT. Then write $\int_{0}^{\infty}=\int_{0}^{1}+\int_{1}^{\infty}$ and estimate these two integral separtely. I think the correct bounded should be $\cdots \leq |h|[K_1\left(\alpha,\beta\right)+K_2\left(\alpha,\beta\right)]$.

Comment: You are welcome, and yes, splitting into the two parts seems a good idea.